# Java ANTLR how to ignore part of rule? ignore part after subrule

Tags: java, antlr, rules

I'm trying to create a compiler using ANTLR and Java. I have this problem where I have a rule and I can't get just a part of it to use. I have a command e.g. 0: HALT 0,0,0 and I want to ignore everything else after that.

e.g.0: HALT 0,0,0 blah blah blah, I want to ignore the blah blah blah

my rule is:

```
    rule returns [String value]
    :
    INTEGER':' ro=rocommand i1=INTEGER',' i2=INTEGER ',' i3=INTEGER rest {$value = $ro.text+" "+$i1.text+","+$i2.text+","+$i3.text;   }
    | INTEGER':' rm=rmcommand j1=INTEGER ',' j2=INTEGER '('j3=INTEGER')' rest {$value = $rm.text+" "+$j1.text+","+$j2.text+"("+$j3.text+")"; }
;
```

and the code I have is:

```
CharStream charStream = new ANTLRStringStream(strLine);
simulatorLexer lexer = new simulatorLexer(charStream);
TokenStream tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
simulatorParser parser = new simulatorParser(tokenStream);
System.out.println(parser.rule());
```

What I get is:

```
0: rule:IN 0,0,0
1: rule:LDC 1,1,0
line 1:15 no viable alternative at character 'r'
line 1:18 no viable alternative at character '='
line 1:15 no viable alternative at character 'i'
```

for the text:

```
0: rule:IN 0,0,0
1: rule:LDC 1,1,0 r1=0
```

So it should parse the first line correctly and the 2nd until the 0. then it should ignore r1=0. It works correctly until now, but it shows a number of errors and I want to get rid of them. Please help me!

### EDIT

I'm posting the whole grammar so you can help me better. I just want to recognize the rule part.

```
program:
    rule+
;


rocommand:
    'HALT'|'IN'|'OUT'|'ADD'|'SUB'|'MUL'|'DIV'|'LDC'
;

rmcommand:
    'LD'|'LDA'|'LDC'|'ST'|'JLT'|'JLE'|'JGE'|'JGT'|'JEQ'|'JNE' 
;

rest:
  ~('\n'|'\r')* '\r'? ('\n'|EOF)
;

rule returns [String value]
    :
    INTEGER':' ro=rocommand i1=INTEGER',' i2=INTEGER ',' i3=INTEGER rest {$value = $ro.text+" "+$i1.text+","+$i2.text+","+$i3.text;   }
    | INTEGER':' rm=rmcommand j1=INTEGER ',' j2=INTEGER '('j3=INTEGER')' rest {$value = $rm.text+" "+$j1.text+","+$j2.text+"("+$j3.text+")"; }
;

WS  : (' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\u000C'|'\n') {$channel=HIDDEN;};
INTEGER : '0'..'9'+;
IGNORELINE : '*' ~('\n'|'\r')* '\r'? '\n' {$channel=HIDDEN;};
```

Comment: Can you post a self containing grammar so that I (or others) can run a generated parser against your input? It's impossible to tell what's wrong without seeing more of your grammar.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I just edited the original post and posted my grammar. Hope you can help me, thanx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with the rule:

```
rest:
  ~('\n'|'\r')* '\r'? ('\n'|EOF)
;
```

Inside parser rules, the `~` negates the entire set of tokens the lexer produces. So `~('\n'|'\r')` does not *not* match a single character other than `'\n'` or `'\r'`. It matches any *token* other than the tokens that matched `\r` or `\n`.

Also, since your lexer puts `'\n'` and `'\r'` on the hidden-channel, these token will not be available in your parser. This means that the `'\n'` in the `rest` rule can never be matched.

In short: you can't "tell" your parser what the end of a line is since these characters are discarded by your `WS` rule. This means you have no way to properly write such a `rest` parser rule.

For your input:

```
0: IN 0,0,0
1: LDC 1,1,0 r1=0
```

*(note that I removed the `'rule:'`'s)*

the following tokens are produced by your lexer:

```
token[type=INTEGER text='0']
token[type=':'     text=':']
token[type='IN'    text='IN']
token[type=INTEGER text='0']
token[type=','     text=',']
token[type=INTEGER text='0']
token[type=','     text=',']
token[type=INTEGER text='0']
token[type=INTEGER text='1']
token[type=':'     text=':']
token[type='LDC'   text='LDC']
token[type=INTEGER text='1']
token[type=','     text=',']
token[type=INTEGER text='1']
token[type=','     text=',']
token[type=INTEGER text='0']
token[type=INTEGER text='1']
token[type=INTEGER text='0']
```

So these are the tokens available in your parser rules.

Note that the following two characters: `'='` and `'r'` cannot be matched by the lexer as you can see by looking at the errors:

```
line 2:13 no viable alternative at character 'r'
line 2:15 no viable alternative at character '='
```

A possible solution would be to create a lexer rule that matches an integer and a colon:

```
START : INTEGER ':';
```

and let your `rule` start with this token:

```
rule
 : START ro=rocommand i1=INTEGER ',' i2=INTEGER ',' i3=INTEGER rest ...
 | ...
 ;
```

That way, your `rest` can match zero or more tokens other than that `START` token:

```
rest
 : ~START*
 ;
```

And to capture the `'='` and `'r'` characters, create an `ANY` rule and put this rule at the end of your lexer rules:

```
ANY : . ; // match any char
```

That way, the parser will create the following parse tree:

[image]

Another solution would be to create a `LINE_BREAK` token:

```
LINE_BREAK : '\r'? '\n' | '\r';
```

*(and remove `\r` and `\n` from `WS`, of course!)*

And do something like this:

```
rule
 : INTEGER ':' ro=rocommand i1=INTEGER ',' i2=INTEGER ',' i3=INTEGER rest LINE_BREAK ...
 | ...
 ;

rest
 : ~LINE_BREAK*
 ;
```

Comment: You Sir, are my hero! Thanks a billion!