# ANTLR 4 Lexer rule : how to ignore a part?

Tags: antlr4

Here is a related topic for previous ANTLR version :

[Java ANTLR how to ignore part of rule? ignore part after subrule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114429/java-antlr-how-to-ignore-part-of-rule-ignore-part-after-subrule)

With a lexer rule like :

```
R1
: [a-zA-Z0-9]* ';'
;
```

For example i have this input text :

```
test;rezrezr
zrezrzerz
```

It will match "test;" wich is correct. I only need the "test" string.

Do i need to take care of ';' character manually in a custom listener for example ? Or is there a way to specify in the grammar that i want to avoid it (only using lexer rules) ?

**UPDATE**

```
test1;rezrezr
zrezrzerz
test2;rezrezr
zrezrzerz
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are trying to do? I have no idea how to answer the question as it's currently written.

Comment: I added an input example, i hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the `;` character, simply remove it from the lexer rule. Note that I also changed the `*` to a `+` to ensure that `R1` is never a zero-length token.

```
R1
  : [a-zA-Z0-9]+
  ;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I just updated my post with a second input.
Is it still possible to get proper strings "test1" and "test2" with lexer rules ?